# difference between playback volume and track volume?

Tags: audio

http://www.mediamonkey.com/sw/webhelp/frame/index.html?volumeleveling.htm

What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

That document explains all of the leveling techniques in the [Basic Concepts page](http://www.mediamonkey.com/sw/webhelp/frame/index.html?volumeleveling.htm), under the 'Volume Leveling' header.

Answer (score 1):

"Playback levelling" analyses the track and stores the results so the player can alter the volume setting to compensate when that track is played.

"Track levelling" does all the same analysis, yet creates a new file so that it would play back at the new volume in all music players - even those that can't read or don't know about the metadata created by the other method.